# Installing Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate on Windows 8

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to install VS 2010 on Windows 8. After install got error log:

```
[06/19/14,00:33:28] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Error code -2068774911 for this component is not recognized.
[06/19/14,00:33:28] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Component Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) returned an unexpected value.
[06/19/14,00:35:15] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) is not installed.
***EndOfSession***�[06/19/14,01:23:16] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Error code -2068774911 for this component is not recognized.
[06/19/14,01:23:16] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Component Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) returned an unexpected value.
[06/19/14,01:23:17] VS70pgui: [2] DepCheck indicates Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) is not installed.
***EndOfSession***�[06/19/14,01:47:32] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Error code -2068774911 for this component is not recognized.
[06/19/14,01:47:32] Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64): [2] Component Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Express Service Pack 1 (x64) returned an unexpected value.
***EndOfSession***�
```

When I tryed to ru Visual Studio got error

```
---------------------------
Microsoft Visual Studio
---------------------------
Cannot create the window.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Are you installing off CD?  MSDN?  Online?

Comment: I'm installing MSDN disc image

Comment: Not sure on that one.  It seems to be a supported OS for VS2010.  I'd contact Microsoft support; setup related issues are free.